# Check application is running in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I check from my application whether another application is running? I know that this has been blocked since Android 5.0, but maybe there is a workaround?

How can I check from my application whether another application is running? I know that this has been blocked since Android 5.0.

Comment: if it was blocked in Android 5, but there would be some workaround then it also would be fixed through almost decade of development... even if there is a workaround - it may work only on very old or particular devices. besides that - thats insecure for user (privacy at least), there is a reason for restricting such possibility

Comment: YOu can use app usage statics api - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics

Answer (score 0):

You can use use getRunningServices instead. Using ActivityManager as follow:

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo rsi : am.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (isCanceled()) {
            return;
        }

        String pkgName = rsi.service.getPackageName();
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work, I'm using android 11 and it returns me 0 processes